# How to parse a config. ini file in another directory in python

Tags: python, parsing, config

I have to parse config.ini file in another directory and read few values using python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

yesterday_date  = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

for name in os.listdir('D:\Test'):
    full_name = os.path.join('D:\Test', name)
    if time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(os.path.getmtime(full_name))) == yesterday_date:
        folder_name_path = 'D:\Test\\' + name

filename_path = folder_name_path + '\\' + 'mentionfilename'
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Desktop\testing_today.xlsx')
df_old = pd.read_excel(filenamepath)
df_new=df.merge(df_old[['mtm','wes','fre']],on='mtm')
writer =pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\Desktop\output.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: I don't know how you manage to write this much code without any description in the question or the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ConfigParser module.Check examples [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples) .

```
import ConfigParser
Config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
Config.read("\\somepath\\config.ini")
Config.sections()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) documentation.

To simple read a `.ini` configuration file from a path, this should get you started:

```
import configparser

# Create config parser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

# Read in config.ini from a path
config.read('path/to/config.ini')

# Do more parsing.
```

The above specifically uses [`configparser.ConfigParser.read()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read) to read in the `.ini` file.

You would need to provide more detail in your question for more in depth parsing help.